# SQL Unique Distinct Column 1 and not the other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unique, distinct

Im trying to run a sql statement that joins 2 tables then and does a distinct on the ID column and runs a where clause to filter the data down to an hour of the day in question.  The result will show me an hour out of the day but will remove the duplicates so that it gives me unique records, i have seen a number of posts some helpful and some confusing. This is what I have so far.

```
  select DISTINCT FinalID,finaltime,finalos
    from dbo.FinalList
    join dbo.Users on dbo.FinalList.FinalID = dbo.Users.usersid 
   WHERE FinalDate >='2014-07-01'
     and finaldate <='2014-07-01'
     and finaltime >='00:00:00'
     and FinalTime <= '00:59:59'
order by FinalDate asc, FinalTime asc
```

If i take away finaltime,finalos and leave select DISTINCT FinalID i get the correct numbers.  But i wanted to see the info from Finaltime and Finalos but as soon as i add these it tries to do a distinct on those columns also and i get dodgy results. Do i do a subquery ? ?

Comment: Can you add some data to help us to understand exactly what you try to do ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to decide which values you want.

Perhaps using `group by` will provide what you want:

```
select FinalID, min(finaltime), max(finaltime),
       min(finalos), max(finalos)
from dbo.FinalList join
     dbo.Users
     on dbo.FinalList.FinalID = dbo.Users.usersid 
where FinalDate >='2014-07-01' and
      finaldate <='2014-07-01' and
      finaltime >='00:00:00' and
      FinalTime <= '00:59:59'
group by FinalId;
```

Comment: I know you just copied from above. But unless these are case-sensitive column names, the first two conditions are obvious just an equality check for '20140701'. And so it also seems the FinalTime tests are unnecessary as well.

Comment: This worked a treat as well as helping me keep my sanity, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement will return you the unique rows. That is being said, unique across the columns you are selecting. So if one of the Col / Row is different than another then it will be output as a result too. You should use MAX or Min and then group by.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you will decide among various records with the same ID but different values for `finaltime` and `finalos`.

I am going to assume that your final time is your latest time (the largest) and that you want the `finalos` value that goes along with that final time.

```
;
WITH A as 
(
   select FinalID
       ,  Finaltime
       ,  Finalos
   from dbo.FinalList
     join dbo.Users 
        on dbo.FinalList.FinalID = dbo.Users.usersid 
   WHERE FinalDate >='2014-07-01'
     and finaldate <='2014-07-01'
     and finaltime >='00:00:00'
     and FinalTime <= '00:59:59'
 )
 ,  B as  
 (
     SELECT  A.FinalID
         ,   A.Finaltime
         ,   A.FinalOS
         ,   RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                           PARTITION BY A.FinalID
                           ORDER BY FinalTime DESC
                         )
     FROM    A
 )
 SELECT  FinalID
    ,    FinalTime
    ,    FinalOS
 FROM    B
 WHERE   B.RowNumber = 1
 ORDER BY
        FinalTime
    ,   FinalOS
```

ETA:  Fixed syntax.